# how can the following equation be obtained with replacing new variables?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following equation:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}h(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} = \tanh(x(t) + h(t)) - h(t)$$

with substituting new variables as $t = \alpha t$ , $x(t) =x (\alpha t)$ and $h(t) = h(\alpha t)$ in above equation, the following equation is obtained:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}h(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} = \alpha \tanh(x(t)+h(t))-\alpha h(t).$$

My question is that how can the last equation be obtained?

Comment: You say $t=\alpha t$? That gives only $\alpha=1$ whenever $t\ne 0.$ What do you mean? Oh, seems you mean $t\mapsto \alpha t.$ That's quite a different thing.

Comment: Maybe $x$ and $h$ functions that allow for a linear property such as: $f(ax)=af(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the new variable $s.$ Then setting $t=\alpha s$ and differentiating $h(t)$ with respect to $s$ gives $$\frac{\mathrm dh(t)}{\mathrm ds}=\frac{\mathrm dh(t)}{\mathrm dt}\frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm ds}=\left[\tanh(x(t)+h(t))-h(t)\right]\alpha.$$

Finally, you may *forget* about the previous role of $t$ and then make the new change of variable $s=t,$ but I don't think this is absolutely necessary, since we've not run out of letters (those who always like thinking in terms of time may prefer the $t,$ though).

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: However; I cannot still obtain the final equation from your equation by replacing $t=s \alpha$. Could you please add this part?

Comment: @aro Oh, I've looked at the given form. I see what you mean now. I should have written $t=\alpla s$ instead of $s=\alpha t.$ Then the result follows. Sorry for this. I'll edit now.

Comment: Thanks you. However; in your equation, instead of $\frac{dh(t)}{dt}$ ,$\frac{dh(t)}{ds}$ have been obtained. Isn't there any difference between them?

Comment: @aro As I said in the comment and answer above, that's just a trivial change of variable. The independent variable is usually considered a dummy. Thus changing it to any letter does not alter the derivative -- it still means the same thing.

Comment: Thank you again.